# Extruder feedrate when loading and unloading filament

Tags: marlin, extrusion

I have an MKS Base 1.4 board with a TFT28 touch screen and a Titan Aero setup.

When I use the load filament command from the touch screen the motor turns at a crazy speed to load filament, whereas if I plug in my laptop and use Repetier host and send a load command it turns at a normal speed.

Is there a section in the Marlin firmware that allows me to set the actual extruding speed during load and unload?

Comment: Please explain how you retract and unretract filament with Repetier Host. E.g. are you using the G10/G11 G-code commands?

Answer (score 1):

Loading and unloading filament through the [LCD options](http://marlinfw.org/docs/features/lcd_menu.html#prepare) is taking care of by [G-code](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M600:_Filament_change_pause) command [M600](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M600.html). The options used when executing the M600 command define where the head goes and how much filament is extruded of which extruder. Apparently, there is a difference in calling the M600 command via the LCD menu or (un)loading filament through the Repetier application.

The Firmware-based and LCD-controlled retract [options](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M600.html) are defined in Marlin Firmware file [Configuration_adv.cfg](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h) (Advanced Pause). The settings for Repetier are probably differently defined than in the advanced configuration file; you should look them up in Repetier. It could well be that separate G-codes (or scripts) are used for this. E.g. [G10](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G10:_Retract) is used to retract filament as set by [M207](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M207:_Set_retract_length) (both length and feed rate!). G-code [G11](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G11:_Unretract) does the opposite, it unretracts the filament as specified by [M208](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M208:_Set_unretract_length).

To answer your question, yes, you need to alter the values of the constants in [Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h) for changing the speed when using the LCD to change the filament:

```
// (mm/s) Unload filament feedrate. This can be pretty fast.
#define FILAMENT_CHANGE_UNLOAD_FEEDRATE     10  
// (mm/s) Load filament feedrate. This can be pretty fast.
#define FILAMENT_CHANGE_FAST_LOAD_FEEDRATE   6
```